# Find multiply duplicates in row ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

We have the following table:

```
create table tab(
       id number,
       date  number,
       date2 number
     )
```

We need to find rows, if they have `date==date2`.

Im trying like this:

```
SELECT date,date2, COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY date,date2
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

But I cant get FULL ROW with ID. how to write a query correctly?

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE DATE=DATE2`

Answer (score 1):

Sample data (with a note that column name can't be just `date` as it is reserved for the `DATE` datatype).

```
SQL> select * from tab;

        ID DATUM      DATUM2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 26.12.2022 26.12.2022
         2 13.08.2022 22.11.2022
         3 26.12.2022 26.12.2022
```

---

> We need to find a rows, if they have date==date2.

That's just

```
SQL> select * from tab where datum = datum2;

        ID DATUM      DATUM2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 26.12.2022 26.12.2022
         3 26.12.2022 26.12.2022
```

---

On the other hand, you said

> i cant get FULL ROW with ID

based on query you posted. It *might* be adjusted:

```
SQL> select * from tab
  2  where (datum, datum2) in (select datum, datum2
  3                            from tab
  4                            group by datum, datum2
  5                            having count(*) > 1
  6                           );

        ID DATUM      DATUM2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 26.12.2022 26.12.2022
         3 26.12.2022 26.12.2022

SQL>
```

if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried this method. returns an error ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: I believe you did it wrong. See edited answer which now contains sample data and *live* execution.